# background change after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

Why on this page:

https://jsfiddle.net/eddnhc5f/

When I press the key `c` on Firefox and Microsoft edge, the background is changed before the alert, but in Opera and Chrome, after I press confirm alert.

```js
function getKeyup(key) {
  if (key == null) {
    keycode = event.keyCode;
    // To Mozilla
  } else {
    keycode = key.keyCode;
  }
}

function TEST() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "BLACK";
  alert('Hello');
  return false;
}

function getKey(key) {
  if (key == null) {
    keycode = event.keyCode;
    // To Mozilla
  } else {
    keycode = key.keyCode;
  }
  if (keycode == 67) {
    //alert(condcheck);

    TEST();
    return false;
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(eventObj) {
    getKey(eventObj);
  });
  $(document).keyup(function(eventObj) {
    getKeyup(eventObj);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
TEST
```

Comment: You can at least fix it with `setTimeout(function(){ alert('Hello'); },0);` so it runs before alert...

Comment: As alert is an asynchronous event that means it can be triggered parallelly.So if the alert event is triggered first then it will block/prompt all other future events until you close the alert box and if it triggers after background is set then there will be sequential effect means first background would be set then alert will be executed and it will block all other events until user closes the alert then again the program will follow normal flow of execution. There might be the issue of thread interpreting in those browsers.

Comment: It's browser specific, i guess the background setting cause some little delay which get's the alert before the changing background, but if you do console.log() before alert, it will execute normally before an alert..

Comment: You might have disabled alerts in your browser settings. Just remove that alert and it should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

check out this     **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eddnhc5f/2/)**

I did change in TEST() function.

```
function getKeyup(key){
    if ( key == null ) {
        keycode = event.keyCode;
    // To Mozilla
    } else {
        keycode = key.keyCode;
    }
}
function TEST()
{
//document.body.style.backgroundColor = "BLACK";
alert('Hello');
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "BLACK";
return false;
}
function getKey(key){
    if ( key == null ) {
        keycode = event.keyCode;
    // To Mozilla
    } else {
        keycode = key.keyCode;
    }
    if (keycode == 67){
        //alert(condcheck);

        TEST();
        return false;
    } 
}
$(document).ready( function (){
    $(document).keydown(function (eventObj){
        getKey(eventObj);
    });
    $(document).keyup(function (eventObj){
        getKeyup(eventObj);
    });    
});
```

Comment: document.body.style.backgroundColor = "BLACK";
insted of this  statement you may write $('body').css('background-color','black');

Comment: Hello
I want first the background color changed and after alert to appear.
Thank you,
Alex

Comment: keep comment line to after alert statement and remove comment lines above alert